# Is it worth it to use Wap to have cellular webpage?

Tags: mobile-browser, wap

Is it worth it to develop [WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAP_Push#WAP_Push) webpage for cellular since now cellular have browser that is really better than before?

I have a PHP website and I would like to increase the use of portable device to use it. Is it worth it to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly, no. I've written WAP pages (it's painful), I've never seen a person use a WAP browser, and for the 4.25 people in the world who do, there are [WAP Gateways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAP_gateway).

Unless your site is geared towards providing WAP friendly content (e.g. bitesize) that people will reload regularly, it's probably more cost effective to provide a static page with a phone number users can call so that you'll *read* them the content they want, than spend any time on WAP.

Comment: Perhaps pipe the users through Google's Web Transcoder - http://google.com/gwt/n then you don't have to worry about the WML conversion, as google will translate your page into WML.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what devices you're targeting. If you want to have the broadest possible range of devices accessing your site, then you would do well to tailor specifically to different device capabilities and some of those devices will only support WAP.
However, if you only want to target higher-end, more modern devices (nokia smartphones, iPhone, G1, etc) then you can build a "traditional" HTML/CSS site and it will render just fine.

Comment: still, you'll want to keep your design clean and test it on those devices, as screen estate is still limited ('though it got a lot better recently).

Answer (score 0):

More than being about technology, mobile internet is about different use cases and design. I recommend reading:

[Designing for the mobile web](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/designing-for-mobile-web/), and
[Mobile Web Design: Tips & Tricks](http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000577.html)