# what are the key rules for making a standard wap webpage

Tags: html, standards-compliance, wap

I need to make a simple webpage that will be supported in all of the phones that has wap (all wap's versions).

The body suppose to contain a very very simple table, but the file needs to be standardized.

How do i do that?

can you post an example or a link?

Thanks

Comment: `The body is very very simple table` I hope you change this!

Comment: The key rule is: [Don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124318/is-it-worth-it-to-use-wap-to-have-cellular-webpage)

Comment: WAP 1.0 is WML, not HTML, there is a big difference. So, what do you aim at?

Comment: @mkimd - Thanks, I need to make a wap page with a simple table inside.

Comment: Agreed, create a normal HTML base page and if your visitors device really is still doing WML (and the user expects your site to work when no other sites do), then redirect the user to your site via http://google.com/gwt/n

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you will need to identify the capability of the device first. You will need to check what markup the device supports. Is it WML? or is it XHTML?

We used WURFL from Sentia Mobile to identify the device capability using the device user agent. For the construction of the mark up we used WALL4PHP but if you are more accustomed to Java, you may opt to use WNG. Basically, this will handle the correct markup to be served on the client.