# How much work to convert a normal site into a WAP enabled site?

Tags: responsive-design, wap

I have made responsive sites before (plenty of times), but this time, I am being asked to make a WAP enabled version of the site as well.

I have done some research, but only have a vague idea of what this means: is it simply just another responsive version (a separate view written in WML vs. HTML), or is it something larger, like an entirely different copy of the site?

Comment: http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/W/WAP.html - looks like you are talking about having to support very small screens size, low memory mobile devices... therefore instead of just hiding parts of the page, only return essential info from server, minimizing javascript operations ect..

Comment: if you really need WAP site - then yes, you should return only small page with [WML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Markup_Language) instead of HTML, but really - it is legacy technology, maybe they just need small HTML site?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Actually...they specifically need to be able to handle legacy devices in this case, because of various parts of the world that this site will be promoted (who have a larger amount of legacy phones still)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it worth it to use Wap to have cellular webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124318/is-it-worth-it-to-use-wap-to-have-cellular-webpage)